# How To Authenticate HumbleBundle

Tags: python, python-requests

I want to write a program to automatically download my Humble Bundle purchases, but I'm struggling to login to the site. I thought that it should be a pretty straightforward process:

```
import requests

LOGIN_URL = "https://www.humblebundle.com/processlogin"

data = {
    "username": "username",
    "password": "top_secret",
}

session = requests.Session()
session.params.update({"ajax": "true"})

response = session.post(LOGIN_URL, data=data)
json = response.json()
print(json)
```

But I get a rather unhelpful failure message

```
{'errors': {'_all': ['Invalid request.']}, 'success': False}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Humble Bundle uses a CAPTCHA to ensure only humans are logged in. Only logged in users seem to be able to retrieve information about their purchases (I have not found another way to authenticate myself).

By design, a CAPTCHA disallows scripts to log in. My best suggestion is to log in with a regular webbrowser, and store the value for the cookie called '_simpleauth_sess' locally. You can use that to retrieve data as if you're logged in.

Here is an example with `requests` library that the OP uses:

```
cookies = dict(_simpleauth_sess='easAFa9afas.......32|32u8')
url = 'https://www.humblebundle.com/api/v1/user/order'
r = requests.get(url, cookies=cookies)
print(r.text)
```

Or a bit more complex:

```
session = requests.Session()
session.cookies.set('_simpleauth_sess', 'easAFa9afas.......32|32u8', 
                    domain='humblebundle.com', path='/')
r = session.get('https://www.humblebundle.com/api/v1/user/order')
for order_id in [v['gamekey'] for v in r.json()]:
    url = 'https://www.humblebundle.com/api/v1/order/{}?wallet_data=true&all_tpkds=true'.format(order_id)
    r = session.get(url)
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that its going to let you do that. If I had to guess you're going to have to use OAuth.